# How to solve ModuleNotFoundError (python3 tabulate module) when tabulate module is already installed?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, import, module, tabulate

A simple command-line game (game 2048) was written in python3 by my friend, and I cannot run it because I have the following error message:

```
File "c:/Python/2048.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tabulate import tabulate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate'
```

I am using windows and I installed tabulate module with this:
pip3 install tabulate
But the error is still there. What can I do?

Comment: Can you run tabulate from commandline?

Comment: Yes, now I tried it works finally in python shell - command line.

Comment: But it is still not working in the code. Should I copy a file somewhere else?

Comment: Which editor do you use? Does this editor have a package manager?

Comment: I use VS code. It has extension manager, but if is search for tabulator, there is just one item, but it is not what I need.